# How to disable GET requests to JSP page?

Tags: jsp

I am fixing some old defects and as part of one defect, I need to make sure that some requests are being only POST to the JSP page instead of a GET request. The application have a form which submits data to another JSP page (I know its wrong and against MVC but too late to fix it), since it is a JSP page, so we can POST the request or else we can GET the request. In case of a malicious user, can read the form and send the request as a GET from the browser like `http://host:80/somejsp.jsp?param=value&param=value` etc. In that case, it becomes a violation. I need to make sure that such GET requests are not processed. One way to do is to perform the below steps in the jsp page -

```
if (request.getMethod().equals("GET")) {
   // reroute the user as it is not a valid req
}
```

Is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Two solutions:

1. Add a `<security-constraint>` with an empty `<auth-constraint>` on an `<url-pattern>` of `*.jsp` and `<http-method>` of `GET` which will block `GET` requests on JSP files to everyone (as suggested by McDowell):

   ```
   <security-constraint>
       <display-name>Restrict GET requests on JSP files</display-name>
       <web-resource-collection>
           <web-resource-name>JSP files</web-resource-name>
           <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
           <http-method>GET</http-method>
       </web-resource-collection>
       <auth-constraint />
   </security-constraint>
   ```
2. Create a `Filter` which listens on an `<url-pattern>` of `*.jsp` and does basically the following in the `doFilter()` method.

   ```
   if (((HttpServletRequest) request).getMethod().equals("GET")) {
       ((HttpServletResponse) response).sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED);
   } else {
       chain.doFilter(request, response);
   }
   ```

No need to copypaste the same over all JSP pages which would only be prone to `IllegalStateException: response already committed` errors.

Answer (score 1):

Add [security constraints](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/tutorial/doc/bncav.html#bncay) to your web.xml prohibiting the request.

Comment: In my case, the users are already authenticated. Still we want to prevent JSP pages from responding to GET requests.